# how to assert a string which contains atleast one number?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, assertion

i want to check if my actual value has any number or string. How do I assert it?

```
public class Regex {

@Test
public static void m1() {
    {
        String str = "12ABC";
        // System.out.println(str.matches("\\d.*")); // true
        // System.out.println(str.matches("[0-9].*")); // true
        Assert.assertEquals(str.matches("\\d.*"), "str");
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To assert that the string has one or more digits, use:

```java
@Test
public static void m1() {
    String str = "12ABC";
    Assert.assertTrue(str.matches(".*\\d.*"));
}
```

Note that the nature of the `String#matches` API is that the pattern will be applied to the entire string.  So `.*\d.*` is the pattern we want here.

Comment: but i am still getting the below error after making the changes
Assert.assertEquals(str.matches(".*\d.*"), "str");


[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.4.0
FAILED: m1
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [str] but found [true]
 at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:99)

Comment: could you please write the code and help me out

Comment: You're not using the code in my answer.  You are still using the old code.

Comment: hi tim I am very very new to code, if it is ok please write the code , I am not getting where to make changes and how.

Comment: Please try my updated answer.